# How to evaluate hostname?

Tags: sed

I need to insert: `-name api@$hostname` at the top of test_file

How would I evaluate `hostname` ?
I tried:

```
sed -i '1s/^/-name api@$hostname \n/' test_file
```

But the result was:

```
-name api@$hostname
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded in single quotes. Try double quotes:

```
sed -i "1s/^/-name api@$hostname \n/" test_file
```

Check also the `i` (insert) command, it's easier than `s///` for these simple situations.

```
sed -i "1i-name api@$hostname" test_file
```

You need to assign a value to the variable first:

```
hostname=$(hostname)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this result: `-name api@` nothing after `@` so it has evaluated `hostname ` as blank string ..

Comment: Have you set `$hostname` to any value?

Comment: I found it, I have to add `()` as  `$(hostname)` thanks